# Eigevalues of block matrix of order $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the eigenvalues of the following block matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix} J_2-I_2 & J_2 & J_2-I_2 &  J_2-I_2 &\cdots & J_2\\ J_2 & J_2-I_2 & J_2 & J_2-I_2 &\cdots &J_2-I_2 \\ J_2-I_2 & J_2 & J_2-I_2 &J_2 & \cdots & J_2-I_2 \\ J_2-I_2 & J_2-I_2 & J_2 & J_2-I_2 & \cdots & J_2-I_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots &  \vdots  \\J_2 & J_2-I_2 & J_2-I_2 & J_2-I_2 & \cdots & J_2-I_2 \end{bmatrix}_{n}$$

Here, $J_2$ is a matrix of order 2 whose all values are $1$s and $I_2$ is an identity matrix of order 2.

Comment: The structure of this block matrix is not clear to me. What determines which entries are $J_p$ and and which are $J_p-I_p$? Also, the matrix of 1s can be written as $uu^T$ where $u$ is a column vector of 1s.

Comment: $J_p$ are placed cyclically.

Comment: In last row it is at first and second last entries.In forth row it is at third and fifth entries.

Comment: Understood. You may want to clarify that in the question itself. On that note, the block-matrices tag would be appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks semiclassical

Comment: I am sorry I have change p by 2

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** *In the current version of the question, we have $p = 2$.*

It looks like your matrix can be written in the form 
$A = J_n \otimes (J_p - I) + B\otimes I$
where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kroncker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and $B$ is the $n \times n$ matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&1&0 && \cdots & 1\\
1&0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&1&0&\ddots&\cdots &\vdots\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots&&0\\
0&\cdots &&&0&1\\
1&0&\cdots&0&1&0}
$$
Note, however, that the two matrices being added commute.  It suffices, then, to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $J_n, (J_p - I), B,$ and $I$ separately, and then use the properties of the Kronecker product and commuting matrices.

---

In fact, following the hint in the comment below: let $F_k$ denote the $k \times k$ [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix).  We find that

$$
(F_n \otimes F_p)^*[J_n \otimes (J_p - I) + B\otimes I](F_n \otimes F_p) = \\
(F_n^*J_n F_n) \otimes ([F_p^*J_p F_p] - I) +
(F_n^*B F_n) \otimes I
$$
where all matrix products in parentheses produce diagonal matrices.  Thus, we have diagonalized $A$, and all that remains is to find the diagonal entries in the above computation.

It is also notable that the eigenvalues of the $n \times n$ and $p \times p$ matrices are simply the eigenvalues of circulant matrices, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Properties).
For example, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $2\cos(2 \pi j/n)$ for $j = 1,\dots,n$ (and $F_n^*BF_n$ has those diagonal values in that order).

Comment: It's worth noting that $B$ above is the simplest symmetric circulant matrix, and is diagonalized by an appropriate Fourier matrix.

Comment: @Semiclassical does that, by any chance, simultaneously diagonalize $J_n$?  I think $J_n$ is technically circulant...

Comment: Hmm, I think so. Though judging by Wikipedia, I should have said [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix).

Comment: @Semiclassical well, that will do it then.

Comment: What is the properties of the Kronecker product and commuting matrices?Are talking about kronecker sum?

Comment: Don't worry about the commuting matrices bit, just notice that we can simultaneously diagonalize everything, as I outline in the second part. I **do** mean the Kronecker product.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not getting second part.Please explain me in detail if possible.Thank you in advance